# При переходе по ссылке НЕ сохраняется выделение выбранного пункта меню

Tags: php, javascript, opencart

Проект на OpenCart, делаю левый SideBar, нужно чтоб выбранный пункт подменю сохранял свойства selected (применяемые свойством js) при переходе по выбранному пункту левого SideBar. В коде используется дописанный рабочий код подменю третьего уровня, может из-за этого в основном коде не идет передача параметров выбранного пункта подменю?
Вот ссылка как это выглядит в jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Alexboo/tkwkpq8r/12/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*$(".leftSideBarSubcategoryList").hide(); /* hidden only leftSideBar */

  $(".box h3").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    var text = $("span", this).text();
    $("span", this).text(text != "^" ? "^" : "v")
  });
  $(".leftSideBarElement").click(function() {
    $(".leftSideBarElement").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.leftSideBar {
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding: 0px;
  /*!!!!!*/
}

.leftSideBarLine {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.leftSideBarSubcategoryList {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.leftSideBarElement {
  font-size: 13px;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #6C6C6C;
}

.leftSideBarCategory {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #6C6C6C;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.expand {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.boldLetter {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Отменяем подчеркивание у ссылки */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="leftSideBar col-md-3 ">
    <div class="box">
      <h3 class="boldLetter leftSideBarCategory">Список №1
        <span class="expand">v</span>
      </h3>
      <ul class="leftSideBarSubcategoryList">
        <div class="leftSideBarLine"></div>
        <a href="#">
          <li class="leftSideBarElement">Пункт №1</li>
        </a>
        <div class="leftSideBarLine"></div>
        <a href="#">
          <li class="leftSideBarElement">Пункт №1</li>
        </a>
        <div class="leftSideBarLine"></div>
        <a href="#">
          <li class="leftSideBarElement">Пункт №1</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
      <div class="leftSideBarLine"></div>
      <h3 class="boldLetter leftSideBarCategory">Список №2
        <span class="expand">v</span>
      </h3>
      <ul class="leftSideBarSubcategoryList">
        <div class="leftSideBarLine"></div>
        <a href="#">
          <li class="leftSideBarElement">Пункт №2</li>
        </a>
        <div class="leftSideBarLine"></div>
        <a href="#">
          <li class="leftSideBarElement">Пункт №2</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Файл catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/category.tpl:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".box h3").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    var text = $("span",this).text();
    $("span",this).text(text != "^" ? "^" : "v")
});
$(".leftSideBarElement").click(function(){
        $("li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
});
</script>
<div class="leftSideBar col-md-3 ">
<div class="box">
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
<?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
<?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
        <h3 class="boldLetter leftSideBarCategory"><?php echo $child['name']; ?>
            <span class="expand">v</span>
        </h3>
        <ul class="leftSideBarSubcategoryList">
            <?php if(isset($child['children_lv3']) && count($child['children_lv3'])>0){ ?>
            <?php foreach ($child['children_lv3'] as $child_lv3) { ?>
                <div class="leftSideBarLine"></div>
                    <a  href="<?php echo $child_lv3['href']; ?>" >
                        <li class="leftSideBarElement ">
                            <?php echo $child_lv3['name']; ?>
                        </li>
                     </a>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Дай вывод готовой страницы в браузере (Ctrl+U)

Comment: Anton, я  добавил в описание вопроса ссылку в jsfiddle, что Вы понимали, что там  происходит

Comment: Ок, гляну сейчас

Comment: Anton, сделал вывод всей страницы в браузере (ctrl+u) и что я там должен увидеть?

Comment: В вашем коде не видно, чтобы php добавлял какие-то классы на ссылки. Похожий функционал я делал для магазина на джумле и ВП на фронтэнде: после загрузки страницы селектором искал ссылки меню, парсил их атрибут "href", если он подходил по регулярке, сравнивающей его с document.location, ссылке добавлял класс "active".

Comment: Не совсем понял при каких условиях не сохраняет "селектед", при сворачивании - сохраняет. уточните пожалуйста

Comment: Он, по-моему, просто не понял, что при переходе на новую страницу сайт в браузере перезагружается, а его скрипт выполняется до перезагрузки страницы. Я описал ,как обычно делаются подобные вещи выше.

Comment: Друзья, я преобразовал ответ (который пока что не был ответом) в комментарий и перенес за ним всё обсуждение. Вы можете [продолжить это обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59114/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Comment: larrymacbarry, в скрипте js применяется класс selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за Ваши рекомендации, которые меня натолкнули на мысль. Вот как я решил этот момент:
в файле  catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/category.tpl:

```
   <?php  foreach ($child['children_lv3'] as $child_lv3) { ?>
     <div class="leftSideBarLine"></div>
     <a  href="<?php echo $child_lv3['href']; ?>" >
         <!-- THIS CONDITION-->
         <?php if($child_lv3['category_id'] == $child_lv3_id) { ?>
             <li class="leftSideBarElement selected">
                 <?php echo $child_lv3['name']; ?>
             </li>
         <?php } else { ?>
             <li class="leftSideBarElement">
                 <?php echo $child_lv3['name']; ?>
             </li>
         <?php } ?>
     </a>
   <?php } ?>
```

И в файле catalog/controller/extension/module/category.php дописать условие:

```
if (isset($parts[2])) {
        $data['child_lv3_id'] = $parts[2];
    } else {
        $data['child_lv3_id'] = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт в вашем примере срабатывает потому, что на элементах меню нет ссылок, соответственно страница не перезагружается. А вот на живом OC магазине скрипт как раз не имеет смысла. Ведь при нажатии на пункт меню происходит переход по ссылке и перезагрузка всей страницы, клик не запоминается. Вам об этом писали в комментариях к вопросу.

В OC для решения этой задачи можно прибегнуть к нескольким вариантам. Я предпочитаю два:  **$data['active']** и **localStorage**. Первый предусматривает определение новой переменной в контроллере того модуля, который отвечает за меню, пункты которого вам надо подсветить. Но это гемор, имхо. Поэтому рекомендую использовать **localStorage(sessionStorage)**.

```
$(".leftSideBarElement").click(function(){
    active_link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    localStorage.setItem('active_link', active_link);
}
$(document).ready(function(){        
    if(localStorage.getItem('active_link')){
        $('a[href^="' + localStorage.getItem('active_link') + '"]').parent('li.leftSideBarElement').addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

З.Ы. Обратите внимание, в своём примере я оборачиваю ссылку так - `<li><a>...</a></li>` а не наоборот. Это [требования W3c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039563/is-it-legal-to-wrap-li-in-a).

Comment: Не собьётся ли ссылка при комбинации ctr + f5? Но это ещё ерунда. Как быть, если ссылки на нужную страницу есть в поисковике гугла или просто ещё где-нибудь на сайте? Они же тогда не попадут в хранилище. Я бы посоветовал использовать мой способ: парсить текущий адрес и выделять соответствующую ссылку, это намного безопаснее. Можно организовать и на бэкэнде, как это делается в некоторых шаблонах php-цмсок.

Comment: В чём-то вы правы. Но надо учитывать характер Opencart. В дефолтных шаблонах (да и во всех мало-мальски продуманных кастомных) основное меню дублируется только в сайдбаре. Т.е. стили будут применены к двум элементам на странице, но ведь это и логично. Что касается мануальнго обновления кеша страницы - localeStorage сохранит свои переменые. Я дал вопрошавшему затравку, захочет - раскопает идеальный для него вариант кода.